# How to Install ClearSans, fontenc

Tags: fonts, installing-fonts

I am sorry if this may appear as a silly question.
I am having some trouble installing a new font, ClearSans (https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/clearsans/).
I have downloaded it, but I have to say the ReadMe file is not really helpful for me. :)
I am using ubuntu, and the preinstalled latex.

Comment: that is already in texlive (since 2019). there should be no need to install it manually.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, uhm ok.  So i cannot understand the latex error.  LaTeX Error: File `ClearSans.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.
<read *>

l.24 \RequirePackage
                    [T1]{fontenc}^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

Comment: well perhaps you didn't install everything in your ubuntu. Or its texlive version is too old.